# Is it capable to run on 64 bit platform?

Tags: c#, winapi, api

```
        var guidComPorts = Guid.Empty;
        UInt32 dwSize;
        IntPtr hDeviceInfo;
        var buffer = new byte[512];
        var providerName = new[] { };
        var spddDeviceInfo = new SpDevinfoData();
        var bStatus = SetupDiClassGuidsFromName("Ports", ref guidComPorts, 1, out dwSize);
        if (bStatus)
        {
            hDeviceInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                ref guidComPorts,
                (IntPtr)null,
                (IntPtr)null,
                DigcfPresent | DigcfProfile);
            if (hDeviceInfo.ToInt32() != 0)
            {

                while (true)
                {
                    spddDeviceInfo.CbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(spddDeviceInfo);// IS IT THIS LINE WORK FOR 64 BIT                        
                    bStatus = SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDeviceInfo, nDevice++, ref spddDeviceInfo);
                    break;
                }

            }


            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Forcing `hDeviceInfo` to 32 bits *might* be a problem, or it might be fine - it depends on what `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` takes... I kinda suspect you should be checking against `!= IntPtr.Zero`

Comment: Check the structure details in pinvoke.net ... I read it's supposed to be 32 bytes in x64 , 28 bytes in x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not 64-bit safe. Although your `hDeviceInfo` is correctly defined as an `IntPtr`, you treat it as a 32-bit value when you're comparing it.

Also, you don't want to compare against `IntPtr.Zero`. [SetupDiGetClassDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551069%28VS.85%29.aspx) returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` when it fails. `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is -1. You have to compare all 64 bits of the value to determine if the function failed. If you try something like:

```
if (hDeviceInfo.ToInt32() != -1)
```

Then you risk an error if the returned value is something like 0x100000001.

Your best bet is to use [SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) rather than `IntPtr`.

Comment: I complete my app developing Class library ,its works for 32 bit system,  I need to deploy to run it freely in 64 bit os,where not to put os "SYSWOW64" bit foloder pls suggest,

Comment: Calling `IntPtr.ToInt32()` when you're running on a 64-bit platform is not a wise choice.