# How to distinguish between usb-serial converters?

Tags: c#

I've got 4 usb-serial converters (Prolific) connected to a usb hub. When i look in Device Manager i see the dynamically assigned Com numbers. But after repluging the hub into another usb port or after system reebot those com numbers will sometimes change. Is there a way to update those numbers for every converter without manually searching for those numbers? Basicly I would like to have a method in my C# project that will look for some unique id for every converter and then get new com numbers. Is there a way to do this (tried some wmi queries but without success)?

Today I thought about a workaround. So I got another question. How to obtain info about a usb hub? Basicly I could somehow find my usb hub and then retrieve info about connected into hub ports devices . Then getting com numbers of those devices would be quite easy through wmi query. I used USBView to see that it is possible to obtain such info. I can see a tree beggining from a Root Hub -> Generic USB Hub -> Prolific USB-to-serial Comm Port , but how to do it in code now. Any ideas?

Comment: No, USB is a bus, it doesn't show a port number.  And yes, painful problem when you're testing (not in production).  Not much you can do beyond plugging them in one after another and observe SerialPort.GetPortNames() in your code.  Having a way to identify the physical device from the device data is the best solution.

Comment: I don't remember many details but each port that's created has an associated registry key (the location depends on the mfg of the usb-serial chip) with which you should be able to distinguish them.

Comment: I switched to using Moxa 8-port PCI serial cards to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Simple, by using win32 native calls you can get,

I just providing a part of code, to help you,

```
var guidComPorts = Guid.Empty;
        UInt32 dwSize;
        IntPtr hDeviceInfo;
        var buffer = new byte[512];
        var providerName = new[] { };
        var spddDeviceInfo = new SpDevinfoData();
        var bStatus = SetupDiClassGuidsFromName("Ports", ref guidComPorts, 1, out dwSize);
        if (bStatus)
        {
            hDeviceInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                ref guidComPorts,
                (IntPtr)null,
                (IntPtr)null,
                DigcfPresent | DigcfProfile);
            if (hDeviceInfo.ToInt32() != 0)
            {

                while (true)
                {
                    spddDeviceInfo.CbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(spddDeviceInfo);// IS IT THIS LINE WORK FOR 64 BIT                        
                    bStatus = SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDeviceInfo, nDevice++, ref spddDeviceInfo);
                    break;
                }

            }


            return;
        }

    }
```

Use this code...

find Friendly names, split string get exact port you look for.
I have completed it,it works fine due to some confidentiality reason can't able to provide full code here.

For More Find this link

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HardwareHelper.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865487/is-it-capable-to-run-on-64-bit-platform

Comment: Ok thanks for replies. @arun I used win32 api calls and based on USBView c# code I found on net. That was very helpful because I am new to win32 api (your sample was motivating ;) ). Quite a lot of code but it works now great as I wanted.